# If value exists in other table, return another value from that table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT video_calls.initiated_user_id AS user_id,
       (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE patients.id = video_calls.initiated_user_id)
            THEN 'patient'
            ELSE (CASE
                      WHEN EXISTS
                             (SELECT *
                              FROM backend_users
                              WHERE backend_users.id = video_calls.initiated_user_id)
                      THEN "%%backend%%"
                      ELSE "unknown"
                  END)
        END) AS user_type
FROM video_calls
WHERE id='7f350a98-93d3-4d21-80a8-6cda3e47a4c0'
UNION
SELECT user_id,
       user_type
FROM channel_joins
WHERE channel_id='7f350a98-93d3-4d21-80a8-6cda3e47a4c0'
```

In the line, where it currently says `THEN "%%backend%%"` I'd like to return the column `backend_users.backend_type` instead, for the corresponding row where the value `video_calls.initiated_user_id` has been found. I suppose I need to work with a JOIN here, but I currently can't figure out where exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a correlated subquery.  You can use that to get the value:

```
        ELSE (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(bu.backend_type), 'unknown')
              FROM backend_users bu
              WHERE bu.id = video_calls.initiated_user_id
             )
```

Note the use of `MAX()`.  This ensures that exactly one value is returned.  If no rows match, the `MAX()` returns `NULL`, so `'unknown'` is returned.

This has one slight nuance from your pseudo-code.  If the matching row is `NULL`, then this returns `'unknown'` rather than `NULL`.  If that is an issue, the logic in the subquery can be tweaked.

Comment: That was easier than I expected. Thought of this too complicated probably, ha. Thank you very much!